# Charge residing on an overpolished surface

Tags: electrostatics, charge

I had very well read that when charge is stored on a rough surface, the leakage is very high from the pointed tips of such surfaces, by a phenomenon called action of points. But now, I've come to know that if a surface is over-polished (or say ideally polished), it becomes very difficult to store charge on it. I'm confused with this. What might be the reason to say so? I do think that by over polishing, you destroy the dielectric layer on the surface of such object (where we tend to store charge) and charge can't be stored easily. But I'm not satisfied with my own logic. So, can someone please clarify it?

Comment: Hi A4kash. I think your question is unclear to me somehow. What do you mean by *storing charges* and *over-polishing*, etc. It makes the question somewhat vague. Can **you** please clarify it for better understanding? ;-)

Comment: I have pasted the exact copy of the question without any omission....the question read: Overpolishing of any surface makes it difficult to store charge on it..WHY???